# Zipall used with float array

Tags: scala

I would like to use a zipall for two arrays having unequal float items. I want to get a dot product of them later. Later I need to sum all elements

```
 (for((a, b) <- x.zipAll(y, 0, 0) yield a * b) sum
```

The error I am getting on this statement is

```
value sum is not a member of Array[Nothing]
```

Please point out my mistake... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntactic error in your for expression: yield comes after closing bracket of for. This should work:

```
(
  for (
    (a, b) <- x.zipAll(y, 0, 0)
  ) yield a * b
).sum
```

Comment: not working.type mismatch; found : Array[Nothing] required: Float.
"(for((a, b) <- x.zip(y)) yield a * b) sum"
this works though. But I need it for dissimilar length arrays

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your efforts. After many changes and reading other reference, the following seems to be working

```
(for ((a, b) <- x.zipAll(y, 0.0f, 0.0f))yield a * b).sum
```

It seems the float value needed the f at the end.